# Flex 4.6 TextInput Keyboard on iOS

Tags: ios, apache-flex, textinput

I have migrated my app from Flex 4.5.1 to Flex 4.6 and the TextInput click event was broken so I do this « skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" » (like was suggest here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS82181550ec4a666a39bafe0312d9a274c00-8000.html) and all seems work (tested in my Android and seems ok) but one user with iOS 5.1 complained that now the keyboard dont popup ?

Also complained for the TextArea that I dont have code in my extended component but also use the skin spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin so the layout became similiar in my textinputs.

Answer (score 1):

TextInput is broken in Flex 4.6

1. It doesn't scroll properly when default TextStageSkin is used
2. It causes some ugly artifacts when the TextStageSkin is used and keyboard resizes the view:
   [ugly flex TextInput bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958027/flex-4-6-air-3-2-textinput-artifacts)
3. It doesn't show proper keyboard type when TextInputSkin is used and softKeyboardType is set to something...

My guess this is a bug in AIR SDK, as there is noting in Flex SDK source which looks like it can be corrected. They gave us an SDK where none of the skins works properly. I hope Apache Flex will be much more mature. But again, this looks like an AIR issue to me.

GL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the opportunity to test a iPad 2 and using the TextInput with skin spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin, the events of flex works but does not open the keypad in iOS and with skin (stagetext new skin), keypad open in iOS (and with native access to spell check, etc ...) but do not run flex events. Since we do not need both situations simultaneously works (which fortunately it's my case for now).