# Flex 4.6 AIR 3.2 TextInput artifacts

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, keyboard, textinput

I'm testing simple TextInput functionality in flex 4.6 + air 3.2 mobile application and observing strange artifacts when soft keyboard resizes the view. Here is appearance:
before soft keyboard is popped out and after.
As you can see Flex has resized the view so that soft kb would with with the TextInput visible. But this is causing erasures artifacts in all TextInputs! Is this a bug? Where in Flex or AIR?
Any suggestions how to fix this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Lots of problems w/ the Flex 4.6 skins which make use of StageText.  You can switch to the old Flex 4.5 mobile TextInput skin which does not use StageText; but then you won't have some StageText specific functionality, like requesting the soft keyboard type.

Comment: Agree, it is sad to see how after they've dropped out Flex, more and more bugs appear in the runtime which makes it practically impossible to target the recent version. For now I'm sorting out to use AIR 3.1 which doesn't resize the view on soft keyboard. Other option is to use the foxhole UI framework built on Starling.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Flex 4.6 uses StageText in it's mobile TextInput skins.  StageText does not render correctly when scrolled.

Use the Flex 4.5 mobile TextInput skin:

```
<s:TextInput skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin"/>
```

Comment: Good try Robert! But what if I desperately need to show the email keyboard type? This won't work with TextInputSkin ;)

Comment: That is a good point.  I haven't tried this, but have you tried using <softKeyboardBehavior>pan</softKeyboardBehavior> in your app descriptor?  I wonder how StageText is treated in that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to 3.3 should resolve this issue

http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2012/06/introducing-air-3-3-and-flash-player-11-3.html

Comment: It is not. I just tested on 3.3 SDK and same behavior. Btw, the other bug when test stays while TextInput scrolls is still there. Seems like folks at Adobe are enjoying playing Angry Birds instead of fixing their ugly bugs.

Comment: I just tested it on Air 3.3.0.365 and it behaves just as bad as ever.

Answer (score 0):

We *might* have a solution to this: http://blog.flexicious.com/post/Scrolling-Issues-With-TextInput-for-Flex-Air-Mobile-Native-StageText.aspx It works for our scenarios, and should for most others.